# MySQL DISTINCT returning not so distinct results

Tags: mysql, distinct, distinct-values

Good day,

I have a small issue with MySQL Distinct.
Trying the following query in my system :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `booking_id`, `booking_ticket`, `booking_price`, `bookingcomment_id`, `bookingcomment_message` FROM `mysystem_booking`
LEFT JOIN `mysystem_bookingcomment` ON `mysystem_booking`.`booking_id` = `mysystem_bookingcomment`.`bookingcomment_link`
WHERE `booking_id` = 29791
```

The point is that there are bookings like *29791* that have many comments added.
Let's say 10. Then when running the above query I see 10 results instead of one.

And that's not the way DISTINCT supposes to work.
I simply want to know if there are any comments. If the comment ID is not 0 then there is a comment. Of course I can add COUNT(blabla) as comment_number but that's a whole different story. For me now I'd like just to have this syntax right.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...` returns distinct rows, looking at your query, each row probably has at least one bit of distinct data per row (probably the comment id and message), thus shows up.

Comment: If there are 10 comments, which one do you want to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try aggregating here, to find which bookings have at least a single comment associated with them:

```
SELECT
    b.booking_id,
    b.booking_ticket,
    b.booking_price
FROM mysystem_booking b
LEFT JOIN mysystem_bookingcomment bc
    ON b.booking_id = bc.bookingcomment_link
WHERE
    b.booking_id = 29791
GROUP BY
    b.booking_id
HAVING
    COUNT(bc.bookingcomment_link) > 0;
```

Note that depending on your MySQL server mode, you might have to also add the `booking_ticket` and `booking_price` columns to the `GROUP BY` clause to get the above query to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using a case when expression

```
SELECT DISTINCT `booking_id`, `booking_ticket`, `booking_price`, `bookingcomment_id`, 
case when `bookingcomment_message`<>'0' then 'No' else 'Yes' end as comments
FROM `mysystem_booking`
LEFT JOIN `mysystem_bookingcomment` ON `mysystem_booking`.`booking_id` = `mysystem_bookingcomment`.`bookingcomment_link`
WHERE `booking_id` = 29791
```